# How to use exception?

Tags: c#, exception

Here is the code that I wrote to understand how exception handling works:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class ExceptionHandling
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("C:\\Sample Files\\Data.txt");    
            Console.WriteLine(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
            streamReader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)    
        {                       
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);       
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);    

        }
    }
}
```

I understand the `try` block, but I am having a hard time to understand how `catch` block works. I know that `Exception` is a `class` and `ex.Message` is the exceptions message.

- My questions is what is `ex`? If this is an object, then how can we use without instantiation? And what does putting Exception ex into parameter of catch do?
- And finally are `try` and `catch` methods? If they yes, are they in `System` namespace?

Comment: Close-voters: Please quote the part of the question which asked us to "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ex` is a variable of type `Exception`.

When code elsewhere fails, it will do something like `throw new Exception("some message here");`.

The `throw` keyword causes the exception (created by `new`) to be passed up the stack, and if it hits your `catch`, that code will execute with `ex` pointing to that exception object.

`throw`, `try`, and `catch` are not functions, they are keywords. They're language features like `foreach` and `if`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) But can you answer my question again? If ex is a variable how can we use ex.Message. I thought in order to get property from a class ex has to be an object. Am I misunderstanding sth? Thank you again

Comment: Yes, you are misunderstanding what "variable" and "object" means, I think. When you declare an `int` like `int number = 123;`, `number` is a variable. It points to an integer, not an object, but it's still a variable. Likewise, `ex` is a variable which points to an object in memory. You could say "ex is an object", but that's short-hand for "the thing that the variable named "ex" points to is an object".

Comment: @JCronin `ex` is a variable of type `Exception`, so it holds a reference to an object of type `Exception` (or a type derived from `Exception`).

Answer (score 4):

`ex` is a variable referring to an exception object that is instantiated by either the object that raised the exception, one of its dependencies, or the .NET runtime.

You can create your own exceptions like any object, and then throw them:

```
var myException = new MyCustomException(/*...*/);
throw myException;
```

[try-catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx) is a statement that is part of the syntax of the C# language.

The `catch` part does not need to reference the exception variable if you do not need to access any of its members in your handling code. The following is valid syntax:

```
try {
    // some code that might throw IO exception
catch (IOException) {
    Console.WriteLine("Exception thrown.");
}
```

Bonus tips:

- It is generally bad practice to catch the base class `Exception` - you should typically [catch the most specific derived exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1411319/177018) that you are trying to handle in your `catch` clause.
- When you are using a class that implements `IDisposable` like `StreamReader`, you should consider using the [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If the code crashes anywhere the it will have because someone has instantiated and thrown (C# `throw` keyword) an instance of an `Exception` (most likely a subtype such as `InvalidOperationException`).

If this exception is raised inside the `try`, the `catch` will attempt to handle it by checking if it can be derived from `Exception` (which all .Net Exceptions do).

If you define a variable to hold the instance of the exception on your catch block the runtime will assign the exception to it.

So `ex` will be set by the runtime to the exception that occurred. Have a look using the Debugger to see more information about it.

You can handle just specific exceptions like so:

```
catch (NullReferenceException nre) { HandleNRE(nre); } //nre will be a NullReferenceException 
catch (InvalidOperationException ioe) { HandleIOE(ioe); } //ioe will be an InvalidOperationException 
catch (Exception e) { HandleEverythingElse(e); } //e will be whatever was thrown.
```

You can also have catch blocks without an `ex`, e.g.

```
catch (NullReferenceException) { /* Do nothing, who cares about nulls. */ }
```